# Window size not fit w.r.t iPhone screen size

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode6

I have made a new application in XCode 6 and when I run the app on simulator the window is of size iPhone4 leaving black spaces above and below window. My application is simple, just on view presented from App Delegate. Please see picture for more elaboration.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Just got the solution, posting here in case someone else need some help with the same issue.
Follow the instructions mentioned here in blog to resolve this issue. [Update Screen Resolution](http://www.raywenderlich.com/33150/how-to-update-your-apps-for-the-4-inch-iphone-5-display)